# List intersection predicate issue

Tags: list, prolog

I'm trying to create this predicate that counts the number of matches from one list to another but whenever I run it I keep getting errors regarding the X and Y values not being instantiated correctly. Does anybody know how to fix this?

```
:- dynamic listCount/1.
listCount(0).

intersection([],_,_).
intersection([H|T], CheckingList, _):-
    member(H,CheckingList),                      %checks if it's within the list
    deleteFromList(CheckingList, H, NewList),    %deletes all occurrences form the list
    listCount(X),                                %retrieves the persistent value
    retractall(listcount(_)),
    Y is X + 1,                                  &increments the value
    assert(listcount(Y)),
    intersection(T, NewList,Y).                  %recurses  on the remaining list
```

Comment: how about accepting one of the answers to your previous question(s)? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several typos (like listcount vs listCount), but overall there is a big misconception: assert/retract are *not* necessary to implement this functionality, and should be avoided. Counting matches can be done (for instance) with library(aggregate):

```
counts_matches(L1,L2,N) :-
  aggregate_all(count, (member(X,L1),memberchk(X,L2)), N).
```

Answer (score 0):

The SWI Prolog has [`intersection` predicate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=intersection%2F3) as part of its library.

If you must write this yourself,

```
my_intersection(A,B,C):-
  findall( X, (member(X,A), memberchk(X,B)), C).
```

you should **not** use here any `assert`/`retract` calls.

Then, trivially,

```
intersection_count(A,B,N):-
  my_intersection(A,B,C),
  length(C,N).
```